# How to add custom header to my dataframe | pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been searching over the internet but could not find proper details

**How to add my custom header to my dataframe**

**Data :**

```
                                       0
0              $5.95,Belgian Waffles,650
1   $7.95,Strawberry Belgian Waffles,900
2  $8.95,Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles,900
3                 $4.50,French Toast,600
4          $6.95,Homestyle Breakfast,950
```

**List:**
`final_data_set` -> This is list which contains data and got above result

**Logic**

```
headerList = [ 'price','name','calories' ]
df = pd.DataFrame(final_data_set)
print(df)
```

**Required :**

Need to remove vertical numbers : `0 1 2 3 4`  and header which is `0`

Required to add header fields as : `price','name','calories`

Need to remove frontend spaces as well

**Expected output :**

```
price,name,calories
$5.95,Belgian Waffles,650
$7.95,Strawberry Belgian Waffles,900
$8.95,Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles,900
$4.50,French Toast,600
$6.95,Homestyle Breakfast,950
```

Comment: How do you read your data? It looks like the columns should have been split already at the read_csv stage (or similar), but were not. Different options to the reading function should fix that.  Fix the reading properly to save you time for the next time you need it, instead of splitting after the fact (unless absolutely needed)

Answer (score 3):

I think the following will help you

```
df = pd.DataFrame(final_data_set, columns=headerList)
```

Comment: Apparently, final_data_set is a list (1 column) and then it won't work to pass three headers.

Answer (score 1):

We should split the data into columns and replace the columns in the dataframe.

```
df = df["0"].str.split(",", -1, expand=True)
df.columns=["price","name","calories"]
```